# Have pure virtual methods always existed in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, abstract-class, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I found some code in a work project that throws errors when a child class has not overridden a base class function (essentially, base classes that use this utility are effectively abstract). When I saw this, my first reaction was, "Why don't they just make those methods pure virtual?" However, the code in question is ~15 years old and I wasn't certain whether or not it was created to fill the gap that pure virtual would fill later (assuming it didn't exist at the time).

- If pure virtual methods have existed since then, is there any reason to provide them additional or alternative functionality? (I realize this may be subjective, but I don't even have a starting point here).
- If they haven't, is there any documentation that points to which standard introduced them?

Comment: They've been existing from the 1st (not standardized) versions of the c++ language versions.

Comment: Some code generators generate those exceptions, sometimes, your implementation might not need that method as it is never called for the limited usages of implementation. In general, pure virtual sounds like the way to go, however, I'm pretty sure that if you would start using it, some code won't compile. Good luck with that!

Comment: As others have pointed out, pure virtual has been in C++ since day 1.  Could you post a sample of this code in the base class?  Is it a compile time or run-time error?   There's some esoteric reasons why someone may have wanted to do things differently, but without seeing the code and error, it's hard to say.  My immediate guess is that there were still a handful of cooky folks at that time who came from the "C" camp and had "heard" that virtual methods were slow.

Comment: To answer your question *why*, perhaps your colleagues were used to programming in a different language, which doesn't support pure virtual functions out-of-the-box (Python < 2.6) or it does support them in a different manner (Java has `abstract` keyword). Or they were just not good C++ programmers and they didn't now such possibility exists. However, possibility exists that this was in fact the only solution. Double check before you start refactoring.

Comment: @George Can you elaborate how this is relevant here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure virtual functions have (always) existed since the first official C++98 standard (and likely earlier).

Refer to ISO/IEC 14882:1998 [class.abstract]

> A class is abstract if it has at least one *pure virtual function*.

Doing some more digging, in Stroustrup's "A History of C++: 1979− 1991" ([pdf](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf)), he mentions abstract classes made an appearance around 1989. Saying

> "The very last feature added to 2.0 before it shipped was abstract classes"